# String tokenizer in Objective-C for iPhone application development

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing a string tokenizer in [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) for an [iPhone application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#Third_party_applications).

I have the result as:

> 1|101|Y|103|Y|105|Y|107|Y|109|Y|111|Y|113|Y|115|Y|

I want to tokenize this string and display each of the values in tabular format. How am I to do it?

I want the result in a tabular format. Like:

```
102 Y
103 Y
..  ...
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If by “tokenizing” you mean simply “splitting on the pipe-sign”, you can use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of `NSString`:

```
 NSString *original = @"1|101|Y|103|Y|105…";
 NSArray *fields = [original componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

“Displaying in a tabular format” doesn’t say much. If you want a classic table, see the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you want this specifically in Objective-C (are you looking for a 
tokenizer class?), but generic strsep() resp. iso-c90 strtok() / strtok_r() do this and they exist on Mac OS X and on iPhone OS. Described here:

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strsep.3.html

These got code quotes as well.

Answer (score -1):

NSString *string = @"1|101|Y|103|Y|105|Y|107|Y|109|Y|111|Y|113|Y|115|Y|";
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];

Comment: Why did you post this when you offer nothing more than the accepted answer from 8 years ago?

Comment: actually I didn't realise it when i Posted the answer.... i will take care of it next tym i post anything....