# not able to take parsed values in string iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

when I am executig this code ..

```
NSMutableArray *feed2  =(NSMutableArray *) [facebook_response objectForKey:@"paging"];
```

in console I am getting ...

```
{
next = "https://graph.facebook.com/xyz/posts?limit=15&&until=1305300725";
previous = "https://graph.facebook.com/xyz/posts?limit=15&&since=1307032141";
}
```

Now

I am trying to take it in the array and from that I am trying to take it in the string...

like this

```
for (i=1; i<[feed2 count]; i++){
    NSString* pagString=[[feed2 objectAtIndex:i]
    NSString* myPaging=[pagString valueForKey:@"next"];
```

}

however it is creshing at the this point..

can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clarify several things in your question such as what you're trying to do, and what you're parsing (JSON I'm assuming).

You should also specify what the crash log says (which I'm assuming is an ***ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException***).

This is so because feed2 is not an array and should not be read as an array (which I can tell looking ar your JSON). It contains no objects so trying to access the first object at index 0 like you're trying to do with `objectAtIndex:`, will cause a crash.

Create feed2 using:

```
NSDictionary *feed2 = (NSDictionary *)[facebook_response objectForKey:@"paging"];
```

In this case it contains key-value pairs so you need only the following to get the string you want:

```
NSString *myPaging = (NSString *)[feed2 valueForKey:@"next"];
```

Comment: sid..thanks it worked...now..in this string i want this number after until ...https://graph.facebook.com/xyz/posts?limit=15&&until=1305300725

Comment: can u tell me how to get it in one more ans...??

Comment: You need to tokenize the string around @"until=". You will get an array of two strings. Refer to this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685797/string-tokenizer-in-objective-c-for-iphone-application-development . The second object in that array will be the number you need. Also, if my answer helped, I would appreciate it if you accept it :)

Comment: i want to accept it asap ..but it showed me that i can only accept it only after 5 mins..so I was waiting :)

Comment: lol sorry my bad.... I've had a run of unaccepted but correct answers recently so just got extra cautious :P